# A way to wrap compiler error messages in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm new to Xcode and find the red error messages difficult to understand because they are usually truncated. Is there a way to make them wrap to a new line so I can see the whole thing?
How do you change the font size of the messages?

Comment: It is a lovely "feechur" of Xcode.  Sometimes you can hover just right and (briefly) get the full message, otherwise you need to consult the compile log which you can access through the error messages tab on the left.  At least that's been my experience.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at some of the new enhancements coming in Xcode 5. I think you will be satisfied with one of them in particular.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I appreciate your help. I think I'll go for Xcode 5 soon. In the meantime, I'm glad to know I'm not overlooking anything too obvious.